# Accessing views in different activities in couchbase Lite

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

I have 1 Activity and 1 fragment which have the following code

Activity 1

```
Database createConn(Database database) {
    try {
        Manager manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(context), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        database = manager.getDatabase("couchbaseevents");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Error getting database", e);
        return database;
    }
    return database;
    }




private com.couchbase.lite.View createView(Database database){
    com.couchbase.lite.View calendarView = database.getView("calendar");
    calendarView.setMap(new Mapper() {
        @Override
        public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
            {
                emitter.emit(document.get("date"),document.get("cost"));
            }
        }
    },"2");
    return calendarView;
    }

Database database = createConn(database);
calendarView = createView(database);
```

Fragment 1

```
Database createConn(Database database) {
    try {
        Manager manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(context), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        database = manager.getDatabase("couchbaseevents");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Error getting database", e);
        return database;
    }
    return database;
    }

Database database = createConn(database);
Query query = database.getView("calendar").createQuery();
```

When I run the query on CBL in fragment I get empty result but if I create `View` in fragment and not in activity I get desired result, But I dont want like that. I want that view should be created in activity and called in fragment. Is this possible? if yes then please give example.